# Eclipse - How to pin editor tabs?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to pin editor tabs [image]
Is there any plugin for that ?

Visual Studio has this property.  [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this eclipse [plugin](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/skins/index.html).

Animated [example](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/skins/extendedvs_ani.gif).
Its not working on Linux. If you are using Windows then this may help.

Comment: this is exactly what i want but not supported on 4.x yet :(

Comment: such a pity, no pin function on mac os x ;(

Answer (score 28):

This is a very old thread but in Eclipse 4.6.3 in order to get the pin icon in the toolbar you need to check the "close editors automatically" option (Preferences -> General -> Editors).

[image: Preferences Window]

[image: Editor Window]

Answer (score 6):

In Eclipse 4.4.0 there You'll find a pin symbol in the default toolbar of Eclipse on the right side.
After clicking it, the Java Editor Tab symbol gets changed indicating this editor is pinned now.
Unfortunatelly I could not find a corresponding entry in the popup menu.
But it is easy to assign e.g. the keys Ctrl-P to "Pin Editor" in the key bindings of Eclipse. (Don't forget to unbind Ctr-P = Print)

**Update** August 2016: In Eclipse Neon 4.6.0 Pin is **not functioning as I can see**, no symbol indicating a pinned editor/tab.

Comment: so i have just downladed latest Eclipse, set Ctrl+P to (only) Pin Editor, but i see no effect whatsoever anywhere :D

Comment: Jaroslav, You open a source code in the editor, then press Ctrl-P, and in the very small filename (tab header) field of the editor there you toggle a small pin symbol - if not, I am wondering...

Comment: yes, i had to play with toolbar (and their buttons) visibility, by default i could not see the button... sadly the whole Pin thing is missing the "Close all but pinned" part :)

Comment: i miss  "Close all but pinned" too - 
at least the auto-close function ("before opening more than x editors auto-close one") respects the pinned ones :)
but overall it his "half cooked" I muss confess